# Interrupt formatting

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

Recently I bought a new HDD and it was formatted as FAT32. I wanted to use NTFS so I started to format it again. On Windows, there is a checkbox labeled "Quick format" (or something like that), which I left turned off. After several hours it processed about 20% of the capacity so I stopped it.

Is it ok to stop the formatting in the middle of work? I then ran the formatting with that "quick" option turned on and it was done in just a little while. My understanding is that that "quick" option installs some kind of tables at the beginning of the HDD so what does "full" formatting do anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the horse's mouth:

> When you choose to run a regular format on a volume, files are removed
>   from the volume that you are formatting and the hard disk is scanned
>   for bad sectors. The scan for bad sectors is responsible for the
>   majority of the time that it takes to format a volume.
>
> If you choose the Quick format option, format removes files from the
>   partition, but does not scan the disk for bad sectors. Only use this
>   option if your hard disk has been previously formatted and you are
>   sure that your hard disk is not damaged.
>
> If you installed Windows XP on a partition that was formatted by using
>   the Quick format option, you can also check your disk by using the
>   chkdsk /r command after the installation of Windows XP is completed.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=302686

Answer (score 0):

A **quick format** rewrites the file directory while a **full format** does the same thing but it  also attempts to read every sector on the partition to validate it.